# Live Wallpaper disappears automatically

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I developed android Live wallpaper using opengl.It starts fine,but it hangs to "loading live wallpaper" very often.I don't know why it is happening.

I have 10 images in drawable which is used for rendering.

My Logcat,

```
        06-27 07:05:26.338: W/Adreno-EGLSUB(22430): <DequeueBuffer:591>: dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
        06-27 07:05:26.338: W/Adreno-ES20(22430): <gl2_surface_swap:43>: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
        06-27 07:05:26.338: W/Adreno-EGL(22430): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3595>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
        06-27 07:05:26.378: W/Adreno-EGLSUB(22430): <DequeueBuffer:591>: dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
        06-27 07:05:26.378: W/Adreno-ES20(22430): <gl2_surface_swap:43>: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
        06-27 07:05:26.378: W/Adreno-EGL(22430): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3595>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
        06-27 07:05:26.428: W/Adreno-EGLSUB(22430): <DequeueBuffer:591>: dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
       06-27 07:05:26.428: W/Adreno-ES20(22430): <gl2_surface_swap:43>: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

Actually My wallpaper loads properly,while it rendering for 30 -50 secs it automatically stops and shows Loading Live wallpaper message.But when when I click settings button it loads again.

Can anyone tell me why I am facing this issue.

Comment: You will have to provide additional info. Does your LogCat show any errors?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Thanks for your commets...Sorry I didn't get any error in my logcat

Comment: Not even in the systemwide one?

Comment: Could you reduce the used images to 1 small one and test again? From what I found it could be a real memory issue or wrongly set buffer sizes.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper same thing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to be a quite elusive bug. Searching for the LogCat messages turns up many questions, but rarely any answers.

Switching of the hardware acceleration worked for some: [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63738)

As this is most likely not an option you could try to change around the initialization routine for OpenGL/Drawing. This seems to have helped some people: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554621/after-a-while-of-usage-my-app-freezes-during-scrolling-a-webview-saying-could), [twoo](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5999), [threee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366537/android-live-wallpaper-doesnt-show)

Without more info available, you will have to try these out (especially the last one) and see what happens.

Comment: I come to knoe it happens because of memory leak in my onDrawFrame method.How can I reduce it?

Comment: The usual: write clean code (no offence intended).
i.e.: Close very stream you open; Dispose all objects that have this function. Don't keep references you no longer need. [Here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=30619.0) is an example